# Calculated formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have 2 drop down fields "City" and "Country". I want a calculated column which will display the first 2 letters from the value selected in drop down fields

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Sharepoint deisgner 2013, you can do this at the workflow level.  There is an action called "Extract Substring from Start of String".  When a user inputs the City and Country fields, use this action to take the first two letters of each field value, and store it in the column you want to have displayed.

**EDIT:**  Updated old answer with answer to original question.

Without having workflows do this, the other way to add this column would have this formula  in a calculated column:

```
CONCATENATE(LEFT([City],2), ",", LEFT([Country],2))
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, is it not possible without workflows?

Comment: I don't prefer workflows as it will take sometime to generate the output and sometimes our servers are really slow...so I am looking for calculated fields option. Any suggestions from anyone?

Comment: Yes!  Let's say city column is called "City", and country column is called "Country".  You can have a calculated column, called whatever, and write it's calculated formula as CONCATENATE(LEFT([City],LEN(2)), ",", LEFT([Country], LEN(2)))

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with the German version of Sharepoint, and German is not my first language, so I don't know all the nuances of Sharepoint just by looking at it :)

Comment: Hi Brandon, It's working but I am getting only the first letter from each column. If I select city as Detroit and Country as USA then I am getting D,U as output. I need the output as "DeUS"

Comment: Change the numbers from 2 to 3 and you should be good!

Comment: Try changing the LEN(#) to 3.  I'm not too familiar with how the LEN function works.  Let me look it up a bit more.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx This is an excellent reference when working with calculated formulas.

Comment: Hi User19952, Yes I already tried changing the numbers...it didn't work

Comment: I think you can write LEFT([City],2).  Sorry, I was looking at the declaration for LEFT() wrong.  The LEN() function returns the length of a column, you don't put integers into the parameter field for that.

Comment: Hey you are right Brandon....it works like a charm...thanks very much friend :)